# Install OS X: USB bootable, launch path not accessible

Tags: macos, boot, usb, osx-mavericks

I am trying to downgrade a MacBook from Yosemite to Mavericks.

I have created a bootable USB with Mavericks, restarted and booted from USB.
When I select *Install OS X* and click *Continue*, nothing happens:

[image: Screenshot OS X Utilities]

I checked the Installer log and this is the error message it is giving me:

`OS X Utilities[384-303] Could not launch application. Exception: launch path not accessible.`

Do you know what could be happening ?!

I would appreciate any information about this, thank you!

Best regards.

Comment: I ended up creating another bootable USB and it worked fine.

Comment: please post that as an answer, @Eduardo

Answer (score 4):

From our experience here, it doesn't matter if you're downgrading or installing OS X from scratch. Also, we had this issue with physical as well as (VMware Fusion 8.1.1 Pro) virtual machines with exactly the described symptoms. *Upgrading* seems to work OK.

The **cause** seems to be that copying the installation file downloaded from the Apple App Store (called `Install OS X Mavericks.app` or `Install OS X Yosemite.app` or `Install OS X El Capitan.app`, couple of GB in size) to a **non-Mac file system** (Linux `ext4fs` shared over Samba here) removes or alters some file meta data. That at least is our best guess about the actual cause.

The file is still good to create USB boot sticks (which later on then expose the same problem) or go through the basics of a VMware VM setup, but when it comes to the point of actually *installing* the OS, clicking the *Install* button does nothing and the error message detailed in the question is printed to the installation log.

**Solution:** Store the installation medium on OS X file systems only.

See also [this VMware forum post](https://communities.vmware.com/thread/523016?start=0&tstart=0) for more information. As mentioned, the problem is not related to VMware though, it's yet another OS X issue.

Comment: As the VMware forum post mentions, you can create a disk image of the app, and then safely store that disk image on foreign filesystems.

Comment: I was able to resolve this issue by running `chmod -R +x .` after changing directories to the USB media.

Comment: Further to @AlexGittemeier's advice, you may also need to mount the volume read-write.

Answer (score 2):

Just chiming in to say I had this issue with a copy of the Mavericks Installer and Alex's answer solved it right away. Just ran `chmod -R +x .` from Terminal in the installer after a `cd ..` all the way up. Used the Terminal to set the date to something believable and everything seems to be moving now. This is all in Parallels on a Late 2019 MacBook Pro for reference.

Answer (score 0):

After following Nick/Alex's suggestion, it turned out that my installation medium was corrupt. Nice thing to discover when you're in a pinch. Probably because I tried to work around a space deficiency and mangled it by putting it on a non-Mac filesystem as per ssc's answer.

The following advice comes with the full awareness that the OP is trying to downgrade, but was the question for which I was looking for an answer, so I'll post it here.

If building a new one isn't on the cards, as it wasn't for me, and you can handle an internet installation, try holding Option+Command+R after turning the computer on.  Release those keys once a spinning globe appears. If you don't have Ethernet connected, it'll prompt you for a WiFi connection. From here, you'll be able to install over the air.  Go find something fun to do if you have a slow internet connection or lousy WiFi (or both).